# Using scanf to re-read a text file in c

Tags: c, scanf

I am currently writing a program in c that requires me to read a text file more than once. That is, I am reading the data from the first line of the text file (which is fine), but then want to go back and re-read the same data from the same first line of the text file again (my problem). The data on the text file are simple numbers spaced out such that they may be read with scanf. I am a beginner and would appreciate some help. If it is in fact not possible to do this using scanf what can I do in order to solve my problem?

Comment: You can't reverse the file pointer with `scanf`/`fscanf`. You have to use `fseek`. BTW, if it is the first line that you want to scan again, just `fclose` the file and `fopen` the file again to reset the file pointer. Why exactly do you want to read the data again?

Comment: Thanks Cool Guy, thats the command that I needed. I have to read the data again because I have to apply the min and max values of the data of the first read in order to change the data accordingly for some calculations I have to do. This may have been possible to have been done using pointers, but I was interested to know if I could do this by avoiding them.

Comment: since it is the same current line, just read the line into a buffer, use sscanf() to extract the values from the buffer,  then the buffer is still available for further reading of the contained data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `rewind(FILE *stream)` it is equivalent to:

```
fseek(stream, 0, SEEK_SET)
```

which sets the file position indicator for the stream pointed to by stream to the beginning of the file